# Interpolate PWD in volumes default value

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would love to be able to set an env variable with default containig `$PWD` call. I need to use the env var in the container later on, but I cant seem to get it to work.

Example:

```
version: '2.3'

services:

  extractor:
    image:xxxxxxxx:0.0.15
    environment:
      - INPUT_PATH
      - CRAWLER_PATH
    depends_on:
      - transformer
    volumes:
      - ${INPUT_PATH:-$PWD/test-data/}:${CRAWLER_PATH-/test-data/}
    restart: always
```

So if not `INPUT_PATH` is set, use the test-data in the current working directory. It works ok for th `CRAWLER_PATH` parameter, but not for `INPUT_PATH`. I tried to set it also in `.env` file but it would not evaluate either. Any ideas, please?

PS: I'm using version `2.3` because need to use `target` property for another service.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible and seems it wont be allowed at no point.

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6030

I worked around by adding variable in the environment as `-CURRENT_PATH=$PWD` and handled it inside the container..